# How to base64 encode a SHA-1 hash in Scala and Play Framework?

Tags: scala, base64, playframework, sha1, java

I would like to base64 encode a generated SHA-1 hash in Scala using Play Framework.

This works for me in Scala:

```
val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
println(new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(md.digest("Foo".getBytes)))
```

But in Play Framework I get an error using:

```
 type encode is not a member of object sun.misc.BASE64Encoder
```

when using:

```
val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
val ha = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder.encode(md.digest(params.get("Foo").getBytes))
```

How can I generate a SHA-1 hash and base64 encode it using Scala and Play Framework?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You seem to have forgotten a pair of parenthesis:

```
val md = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1")
val ha = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(md.digest(params.get("Foo").getBytes))
```

That should work better.

Answer (score 8):

Faster and cleaner with Play api :

```
var signature = play.api.libs.Codecs.sha1(md.digest("Foo".getBytes))
```

**Play 2.7** (possible also older versions)

```
var signature = play.api.libs.Codecs.sha1("Foo")
```

Comment: just `play.api.libs.Codecs.sha1("Foo".getBytes)`

Comment: @Intracer I fixed the response according to your comment - it is now even simpler;)